# Is it possible to get specific Asian population totals from the Census at the Block or Block Group level?

Tags: data, united-states, census

I know you can get it at the Tract level but I can't for the life of me find it at at a lower level. I can find totals for just "Asian" at these levels but I want it to be more specific than that (e.g. Chinese, Korean, Vietnamese, etc.) and specifically in California.

Is this type of information available at the block or block group level?

Comment: I think this question would be more suitable for the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.